# Partial Design Site Specific content

Tags: sxa

We have a shared SXA site that has a partial design for header , the header partial design contains  logo and login rendering competent , we need to use this partial design  in two other sites and change the logo and login URL.

Is there a way to change the logo URL and login URL to be per site configured , Can the data source accept token like $site/Data/login/..

In SXA documentation it mentioned we can use a base partial design but I cant reference a based partial design from the master site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is there a way to change the logo URL and login URL to be per site configured , Can the data source accept token like $site/Data/login/..***

Yes. Just remember to use `query:` token, here is an example for the image:

```
$site/Data/Images/footerLogo
```

***In SXA documentation it mentioned we can use a base partial design but I cant reference a based partial design from the master site***

Did you configure your shared site properly? (set it to be a base site on a tenant)

Here is [Sitecore doc](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/share-data-sources-and-presentation-using-the-multisite-feature.html) wit detailed instructions.

You should see something like this.

[image]

Alternatively you can just put there `ID` of your partial (raw values).